# compiling in windows creates an executable which requires super user mode

Tags: windows-7, cmake, msys

I just create a little application which uses some windows api calls (mostly threads related stuff). The problem is, the generated program needs to be run as an administrator. The cmake script is this:

```
project(myproject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_executable(myproject main.cc myproject-client.cc)
```

and I run it with this command:

```
cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles" .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: when you say "needs to be run as administrator" do you mean Windows is prompting you and you don't know why, or that it doesn't work unless you deliberately right-click run-as-admin? And if the latter, please provide details about "doesn't work".

Comment: Windows is prompting me. Moreover, the exe icon has the shield symbol which means the program requires administrator permissions.

Comment: So your problem is "why does the shield appear" and chances are the answer is "because of the name of the exe". What is that name?

Comment: 1-up.exe I also discover that doing compilation "out directory" solves the problem. Which is ok but still is confusing

Comment: Point of clarification: CMake does nothing that causes executables to require administrative privileges. The way the question's title is phrased implies that CMake is doing this... that's not the case.

Comment: I change the title to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you once ran the application and were told "this application may not have run correctly" by Windows, resulting in a policy somewhere on your machine that memorized "this app needs to be elevated". There is little or no documentation on this process or how to undo it, but renaming the app or building it into a different path often gets you out from under the policy.

You might also try adding a manifest that explicitly states you do not need to elevate, that you will run asInvoker.